# Question about meaning of "That's slang for hair and makeup, spanx, just a touch of bee pollen"

Tags: meaning

Here  is the sentence I don't understand easily. I can't get it the second sentence. It looks like joke but not sure.

> Please, no pics or autographs until I go through the works. *That's slang for 
>   hair and makeup, spanx, just a touch of bee pollen.*

Could you help me?

Answer (score 5):

*The works* is slang to mean *everything*.

> A pizza with *the works* please.
>   *a pizza with everything on it*

this might include sausage, salami, pepperoni, tomatoes, peppers, onions, mushrooms, capers, anchovies, olives, and possibly extra cheeses.

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [camsbar.com](http://camsbar.com/images/demo/menu-main/everything_pizza.jpg))</sub>

The speaker of your passage is saying she is not camera ready until she has put on her makeup, fixed her hair, put on her spanx (body forming support undergarment) and added a touch of bee pollen to get that healthy glow: her beauty works.

[image: here]